# How to Implement this slider in Html/Css and React js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to Html/Css and React js.I am pretty confused and i Don't know how to start this slider If anyone has an Idea how to Implement this or any jsfiddle .Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have basic example, just create input with range type, create onChange method and bind it to input onChange method, all you need then is to style your component, hope it helps :)

```js
class Slider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sliderValue: 0,
    }
  }
  
  onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({ sliderValue: e.target.value });
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <span class="range-slider__value">{this.state.sliderValue}</span>
        <input className="range-slider__range" type="range" value={this.state.sliderValue} min="0" max="500" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Slider />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```